# How to extract file lists using modified date- process Powershell or Batch

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Important

Searched all around but couldn't find any solutions.

Trying to extract few files on specific date using Power shell. I'm new to this concept.

Requirement: There are few files in one folder with different modified date. Script should pick the files name according to the modified date. If suppose i'm running the script today- it should pick only the today's modified date files. As a parameter, it should take the system date (get-Date).

Ex: a.xml file  b.xml file  c.xml file with different modified date

As per above example- need to extract the list of files according to modified date. Same like everyday it has to pick only the files list on present day using system date as parameter value.

Tried:

```
  $time = (Get-Date)
  Get-ChildItem C:\Users\manians\Desktop\PH_PROD\ *.pdf -Recurse | ` Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $time}|select -Property name, fullName, LastWriteTime| Export-Csv 'C:\Users\manians\Desktop\PH_PROD\fileAndDate.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: what is the actual name of each file? your sample looks like it MAY be three files with no extensions - but that is not clear to me. i presume you want the date string from the file name, not the filesystem date info. [*grin*] ---- also, is the 1st one missing a `/` after the `11`?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Those files are xml files. I want to extract based on date wise. Everyday, script has to run to extract the files list using presen date as a parameter.

Comment: so ... the date is IN the file? without the actual XML content, there is no way to guess where the date will be or how to find it. [*frown*] you are not providing enuf meaningful detail to make any kind of useful attempt at whatever it is you want done. [*sigh ...*]

Comment: No No. Actually, I mean to say modified date of those files.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad, you give no examples, not attempts etc. I can help, but you need to help me, help you. The filenames is not possible as `/` are not allowed in filenames.. you get my drift?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Will provide more clarification below mate. There are few files in one folder with different modified date. Script should pick the files name according to the modified date. If suppose i'm running the script today- it should pick only the today's modified date files. As a parameter, it should take the system date (get-Date). Hope this clarifies, Please let me know if anymore details required. I'm totally stuck on this.

Comment: no, not below. please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53367920/edit) your question and clarify.

Comment: **Hi Gerhard**, Sorry for the inconvenience. I have added more details to clarify. Please let me know if more details required.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the objects in the current directory modified today with this:

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime.Date -eq (Get-Date).Date}
```

Comment: maybe the question was how to get files with yesterday's date?? Hint: `AddDays(-1)`

Comment: If we add - AddDays(-1). It takes all the records older than today. If, we required only previous day data?